# How can I distinguish my team from zombies in L4D2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I am having a trouble distinguishing the players in my team from zombies in Left 4 Dead 2, which often results in shooting my teammates when we're trying to fight off a horde.

Is there some sort of way to turn on the name indicators etc?

Comment: "Do... I... look... like one of them?!" - "Yes. Louis. Yes, you do."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team members have a soft outline around them which is more easily seen when looking at them through walls, you will just have to be more careful and look more closely. This adds to the realism I guess and makes the game that slight bit more difficult

> Note that the outline is not visible when playing on "realism" difficulty

Comment: Note that this won't appear if you turn on _Realism_